# I cant create files on my hdd

Tags: files, dolphin

[image: **enter image description here**]

//Im not able to create any file or extract anything to my hdd. Im using pop os and kde plasma. i have attached a ss regarding my problem. Help please.

Comment: I don't know what I should be looking at in your screenshot or what specific issue you are having. Please update your question to describe you issue more precisely.

Comment: Does the parent directory have `write` permission?

Answer (score 1):

As you see, the ownership is of the directory is set to root.

The command line is the most straight forward method to solve your problem. If you have any problem feel free to ask.

You can

1. Use `sudo` or log in as root each time when modifying data on the HDD (not reply recommended)
2. Change permission of the desired location: `chown -R yourUser /path/to/your/directory` from command line
3. Mount the drive with write permission from the start: [Mount USB with write permission for everyone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251206/mount-usb-drive-with-write-permissions-for-everyone-or-specific-user)